# accessing transition history via JIRA REST API

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

I found another person apparently having this issue but I thought I'd re-ask the question to see if I could make it more explicit.

I'm using the JIRA 6 REST web API and successfully pulling lots of data that matches our web cloud UI.

Now I'd like to see the transitions a given issue has been thru, preferably with info about who performed the transition.

I can see this transition history in our JIRA web UI but I haven't figured out how to access programmatically yet.

There's a promising sounding API:

http://example.com:8080/jira/rest/api/2/issue/{issueIdOrKey}/transitions [GET, POST]

And this is the API the previous asker seemed to have been using.  From what I can tell it only returns the valid transitions you can ask for on the issue at a given point in time.

I would like a history of transitions, such as when the issue went to code review, QA, closed, etc.

I have done a expand=changelog but the change log does not correlate with the transitions that I can see.

Any tips would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you use `expand=changelog`, then all changes that have been done in issue are there. Exactly same info as in All tab in Activity section when viewing in web browser.

When I send:

`http://jira.my.server.se/rest/api/2/issue/KEYF-42346?expand=changelog`

Under `changelog`key I find list of `histories`. Each `history`has list of items. Those items are changes performed on the certain field, with to and from values.

To find all status changes you need to do something like this:

```
for history in issue.changelog.histories:
    for item in history.items:
        if item.field == "status":
            print item.toString # new value
            print item.fromString # old value
```

Or use `GET /rest/api/3/issue/{issueIdOrKey}/changelog` like explained in the ["get changelog" docs](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/#api-rest-api-3-issue-issueIdOrKey-changelog-get)

Comment: Thanks.  I was failing to enumerate the inner items so I was missing some status.

Comment: how to narrow down the changelog only to state transition history, instead of all changes made to the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the **jql** parameter for the REST API call.

So your call for,
JQL = *project=XYZ and status was resolved*
fields = key

will look like this,
http://example.com/rest/api/2/search?jql=project%3DXYZ%20and%20status%20was%20resolved&fields=key

where key will return only relevant information and not excessive for each issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void changeStatus(IssueRestClient iRestClient,
        List<Statuses> JiraStatuses, String key) {
    String status = "To Do";
    for (Statuses statuses : vOneToJiraStatuses) {
        if (1 == statuses.compareTo(status)) {
            try {
                String _transition = statuses.getTransition();
                Issue issue = iRestClient.getIssue(key).get();
                Transition transition = getTransition(iRestClient, issue,
                        _transition);
                if (!(isBlankOrNull(transition))) {

                    if (!(issue.getStatus().getName()
                            .equalsIgnoreCase(_transition)))
                        transition(transition, issue, null, iRestClient,
                                status);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Constants.ERROR.info(Level.INFO, e);

            }
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

List is a pojo implementation where statuses and transitions defined in xml are injected through setter/constructor.

```
private void transition(Transition transition, Issue issue,
        FieldInput fieldInput, IssueRestClient issueRestClient,
        String status) throws Exception {

    if (isBlankOrNull(fieldInput)) {
        TransitionInput transitionInput = new TransitionInput(
                transition.getId());

                issueRestClient.transition(issue, transitionInput).claim();
        Constants.REPORT.info("Status Updated for : " + issue.getKey());
    } else {
        TransitionInput transitionInput = new TransitionInput(
                transition.getId());
        issueRestClient.transition(issue, transitionInput).claim();
        Constants.REPORT.info("Status Updated for : " + issue.getKey());

    }
}

public Transition getTransition(IssueRestClient issueRestClient,
        Issue issue, String _transition) {

        Promise<Iterable<Transition>> ptransitions = issueRestClient
            .getTransitions(issue);
    Iterable<Transition> transitions = ptransitions.claim();
    for (Transition transition : transitions) {

        if (transition.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(_transition)) {
            return transition;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

In Short using Transition API of JIRA we can fetch all the transitions to set statuses